# Can I factory reset a non-rooted pixel 2 with a bad digitizer?

Tags: factory-reset

I have a Pixel 2 with a broken digitizer.  I'd like to wipe it of personal data before tossing it.

Complications:

- not rooted
- adb has not been previously authorized.

Is a factory reset possible, or should I pull out the cordless drill and go to town?

Comment: Related: [Razr Maxx HD, How to wipe data with broken screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/45700/3573). If you don't care about data look into [fastboot mode](https://source.android.com/setup/build/running)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Pixel 2 supports OTG, you should be able to attach a usb mouse to it to navigate through the menu. You will need an OTG cable for this, which is available for a small price in your favorite shop if you don't have one yet.